# CrystalReportViewer does not display Charts

Tags: crystal-reports

My CrystalReportViewer won't display the charts in my Crystal Report. I get a red X.
I am using C# and MVC. I've read somewhere that I might need a virtual path to the image folder, but I am not really sure what that means as my chart is embedded in the report... Maybe I am missing something. Can anyone elaborate?

Comment: This link has usefulinfo:

http://www.sdn.sap.com/irj/boc/index?rid=/library/uuid/a0437ea8-97d2-2b10-2795-c202a76a5e80&overridelayout=true

Answer (score 4):

OK. I figured it out...  MVC, like I said, is processing the route rather than letting the CrystalImageHandler handle it. So here are the steps to make MVC and Crystal ReportViewer display images work.

1. Read [this link](http://www.sdn.sap.com/irj/boc/index?rid=/library/uuid/a0437ea8-97d2-2b10-2795-c202a76a5e80&overridelayout=true) and follow the web.config instructions. Make sure all the assemblies point to version 12. You will actually need to install the Crystal Runtime and or Crystal to get the latest assembly versions.
2. Add this line to your `global.asax` file to ignore the route of the CrystalImageHandler:

   ```
   routes.IgnoreRoute("{*allaspx}", new { allaspx = @".*(CrystalImageHandler).*" });
   ```

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem with crystal reports imbedded with chart / graphs.  Using MVC3 framework and crystal report runtime v10

Add the following lines to Web.config

```
<appSettings>
<!-- For Crystal reports to render dynamic images (eg. charts, graphs)-->
   <add key="CrystalImageCleaner-AutoStart" value="true" />
   <add key="CrystalImageCleaner-Sleep" value="60000" />
   <add key="CrystalImageCleaner-Age" value="120000" />
  </appSettings>

<system.web>
<httpHandlers>
      <add verb="GET" path="CrystalImageHandler.aspx" type="CrystalDecisions.Web.CrystalImageHandler, CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
    </httpHandlers>

</system.web>
```

Add this in the method RegisterRoutes in Globalasax

```
/*Added for Crystal reports*/
routes.IgnoreRoute("{*allaspx}", new { allaspx = @".*(CrystalImageHandler).*" });
```

Answer (score 0):

Copy `pg32conv.dll` and `sscsdk80.dll` to `Windows\System32`.

Answer (score 0):

i am also facing same problem while create my crystal report with chart(graphical representation ) , i am unable to get image of chart then 
i add some code in web.config file

below the `<appSettings></appSettings>` tag 
we have a tag like

```
<httpHandlers> </httpHandlers>
```

check we are having the code in between above taghttphandlers,

```
<add verb="GET" path="CrystalImageHandler.aspx" type="CrystalDecisions.Web.CrystalImageHandler, CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=10.5.3700.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
```

if it is there then we definetly get image of chart or bar what ever 
if it is not there plz add the code like above k

i hope this is useful to all
thanks.